# Magento custom jquery ajax not working in server but working in live

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, server

Hi I am new to magneto I have created a separate module to duplicate a product through jquery ajax while click a individual product the product have been duplicating successfully in my local while in the server side its not working its shows the below error.

```
http://example.com/advert_live/index.php/helloworld/index/ 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

The ajax is showing the above error and while using a simple echo code the jquery ajax is working in the server while putting the code for duplicating a product the ajax shows the 503 error. Below is my duplicating a product code. Can you please help me to solve this issue.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

umask(0);
Mage::app(‘default’);
class Magentotutorial_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        
    public function indexAction() {

        $final = $_POST['value'];
        $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $_product = $obj->load($final); 
        $newProduct = $_product->duplicate();
        $newProduct->setStatus(1);
        $newProduct->setSku('value'.$final);
        $newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);

    }

}
```

I have called the jquery ajax below is the ajax code

```
  <script>
                        var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
                        jq(document).ready(function(){
                            jq(".adv_listing_duplicate" ).on( "click", function() {
                                var id= this.id;
                            var uniqu_number = id.split("_");

                            var unique  = uniqu_number[3];

jq.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data :{'value':unique},
            url :"<?php echo $this->getUrl('helloworld/index',array('_secure'=>true)); ?>",
            success:function(data1){

                alert('Your product have been duplicated succesfully');

              },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);},

        });
         });
          });
</script>
```